# Displacement stetched out, how to rezise it?

Tags: texturing, uv, eevee-render-engine, displacement

I'm applying a displacement map on my ground, but when I do, it's stretched out and it doesn't match the scale of my texture. I used a displace modifier and a subdivision too.

[image]

Here is the nodes that i used on shading (for the good purpose of my project I muted the two first nodes to have a matching scale, which is too big).

[image]

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: apply the scale of your object, also make sure that the UV is not stretched in the UV Editor? I'm not sure what's the material has to do with your question as it looks like you're talking about the Displace modifier

Comment: @moonboots. Thank yuou for your answer.
I want the displacement to be exactly where it appears on my texture no matter the scale.
for exemple: I reduced the size of my texture but the displacement does not match it. The "bumps" are way off.

Comment: For fastest response share your blend just with the ground ... https://blend-exchange.com try to delete all parts that dent participate on the issue ... Thanks

Comment: As Vklidu says please share your file, make sure that you've packed the images before saving (File > External Data > Pack Resources)

Comment: It looks like he wants the mapping of the displacement texture to update simultaneously with the mapping of the texture from the texture nodes, so it's better to use a node set-up instead of the modifier, though the downside is that it is cycles only and render view only.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the displacement modifier, you could try displacing it in the render. Take your displacement texture and plug it into a displacement node. If you don't have one, just add a colour ramp between the coloured image and the displacement node. Connect the displacement node to the displacement input of the material output node. Now go to the material properties tab on the sidebar, scroll down to settings>change it from bump to displacement and bump. Now if you scale the texture through the mapping node your displacement will also be scaled. This works in only cycles render mode though, which I guess you're using. Increase the subdivisions (remove the displacement modifier, you won't need it now) if it's not that high res displacement or change cycles from supported to experimental in the render properties tab. You can now enable adaptive subdivision on the subdivision surface modifier which will give you a high res mesh and will save render time. If you still want to use the displacement modifer instead of this material setup, you will have to manually change the scale of the texture in the displacement modifier along with the material mapping.